# Combine network host and bridge for Nginx and Django

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am dockerizing a Django application, using also Nginx as proxy.
My problems is that the DB is running (non dockerized) on the same machine of the where the dockers are hosted.
Therefore, i have to use network_mode: "host" for the django app in order to connect to the db using localhost.
On the other side, if I do so, the nginx image is not able to reach the Django app anymore and gives

```
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream
```

My docker compose file is the following:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: sh /start.sh
    networks: 
      - db_network
      - web_network
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/allarmi/src/AllarmiWs/static
    expose:
      - 8001
    environment:
      - DEBUG=0
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=AllarmiWs.settings.deploy

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    depends_on:
      - web
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/allarmi/src/AllarmiWs/static
    networks: 
      - web_network

volumes:
  static_volume:


networks:
  web_network:
    driver: bridge
  db_network:
    driver: host
```

This is my nginx.conf file

```
upstream allarmi {
    server web:8001;
}

server {

    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://allarmi;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /allarmi/src/AllarmiWs/static/;
    }

}
```

How can I do it

Comment: It's not problem of DB. Please show your nginx config. As usual it placed somewhere there: `/etc/nginc/conf/default.conf`

Comment: `On the other side, if I do so, the nginx image is not able to reach the Django app anymore and gives ` - Are you sure that nginx can connect without placing Django and DB on the same host ?

Comment: `network_mode: host` is kind of a hack.  You'd almost always prefer standard Docker inter-container networking, and to make the host name of the database configurable as an environment variable.

Comment: The dB is on the same machine, thus reachable via localhost. Of course only with network_mode: host enable. If I enable it, nginx cannot reach my Django app